# The Object specified does not belong to a list when trying to get SPFolder as SPListItem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have an extension method that accepts SPListItem. In this particular case, I was working with SPFolder so I was trying to get the SPListItem equivalent of SPFolder(or simply cast SPFolder object to SPListItem Object). I did
            web.GetFodler("FolderName").Item but I keep on getting the error mentioned(i.e. "The Object specified does not belong to a list ")  Any idea how I can accomplish this?

The Extension method is called from this block of code and Exception is thrown at web.GetFolder(officeName + "-Private").Item,

```
if(web.GetFolder(officeName + "-Private") !=null && web.GetFolder(officeName + "-Public") !=null )
                    {
                       officeFolders.Add(officeName + "-Private");
                       var permissionGroup = ExtensionMethods.GetPermissionGroupNameForOffice(office.OfficeCode);
                       var roleNames = new string[] { Constants.CONTRIBUTE_PERMISSION };
                       ExtensionMethods.SetUniquePermissions(web.GetFolder(officeName + "-Private").Item, permissionGroup, roleNames);                         

                       officeFolders.Add(officeName + "-Public");
                       roleNames = new string[] { Constants.CONTRIBUTE_PERMISSION };
                       ExtensionMethods.SetUniquePermissions(web.GetFolder(officeName + "-Private").Item, Constants.VIEWERS_GROUP, roleNames);                          
                    }
```

The Extension method

```
public static void SetUniquePermissions(this SPListItem item, string groupName, params string[] roleNames)
        {
            SPWeb web = item.Web;
            SPGroup group = null;

            try
            {
                group = web.SiteGroups[groupName];
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Logger.LogError("Unable to find permission group " + groupName, "");
            }

            if (group != null) item.SetUniquePermissions(group, roleNames);
        }
```

Appreciate it!

Comment: Could you please share the code?

Comment: I included the code snippets now, Could you take a look?